# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect +spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I searched for this problem and as I got it has some problems with naming conflicts, but again I could not find the reason. I would appreciate the helps. following is the line in the .jsp which calls the controller:

```
<td>
    <a href="message/createMessage">
        Reply
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="${message.fromUser}">
</td>
```

`${message.fromUser}` gets the required property from the model. I am sure it is not the reason for the problem because of other link in this page which works and uses the same model. The controller is as follow:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/message")
public class MessageController
{

    @RequestMapping("createMessage")
    public String createMessage(
        @RequestParam("receiver") String receiver,
        HttpSession session,
        Model model)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageDAO mDao = new MessageDAO();
            Message message = new Message();
            String fromUser = (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
            message.setFromUser(fromUser);
            message.setUserName(receiver);
            Message message2 = mDao.create(message);
            model.addAttribute(message);

            return "newMessage";

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Can't create message!");
            return "redirect:/"; // ?? should add a dialog box for error
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

as an attempt to solve the problem and based on the first answer I tried to use url-rewriting. used @PathVariable("receiver") in my controller. still the same problem. I have added the full revised jsp here: error happens when I click reply link for a message.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>welcome ${sessionScope.user.userName}</h1>

<form:form method="POST" action="message/deleteMessage">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Message ID</th>
        <th>From User</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Reply to User</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="message"  >
    <tr>
      <td>${message.messageID}</td>
      <td>${message.fromUser}</td>
      <td>${message.message}</td>
      <td>${message.messageDate}</td>
      <td><a href="message/createMessage?receiver=${message.fromUser}">Reply</a></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="${message.messageID}"> </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" value="Delete selected messages"></td></tr>    

</table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: sorry, I did not mention it in the text.  It is the title end error "http400- The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" . nothing else is given in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "form" you have a plain html hyperlink that doesn't do any form submit(so the value of the hidden field is never being sent.

So you need to declare a `<FORM action= 'message/createMessage' >` element.

Then you need to either submit the form with AJAX or create a submit button. Another way is to pass receiver value manually by appending the value of the form `createMessage?receiver=someValue`(I added this as example I don't think it's a recommended way, everything has its pros n' cons anyway).

So there are many ways to pass the parameter.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Comment: Thank you. I did this change in my jsp, also changed the argument of the controller method as follow:  public String createMessage(@PathVariable("receiver") String receiver, HttpSession session, Model model)

Comment: I will add the complete revised jsp as an answer. thank you for your help

Comment: @BobbyF I think that `@RequestParam` will also work - because it's the way the GET method passes its parameters

Comment: @BobbyF Please show the `@RequestMapping` that you are using with the `@PathVariable`

Comment: Also `@RequestParam` should work for the standard `GET` parameters. The syntax of request mapping for `@PathVariable` is different.

Comment: @BobbyF is it working with the `@RequestParam` ? Do you see the parameters in the address bar when you hit the link?

Comment: Thank you. the problem solved. I used @RequestParam again as it is shown above in the controller. Thank you so much for your help.